# Subscription form with Django and jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, forms

I've been doing this page in which one can subscribe to the site, and I've been trying to fire the form with jQuery in a Django template.
Now, if a user wants to subscribe, the registration page opens correctly and, in case everything's good, the registration goes well and it goes back to the homepage where it'll be possible to login; in case there are errors (bad username or email or password), it goes back to the homepage without pointing out any error - and only when you go to click again to open the registration form the error is indicated.

I'll copy-paste my code.

- homepage.html

```html
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
 <h2>Welcome back, {{ user.username }}. Let's explore the World together!</h2>
 {% else %}
 
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <h2><button id="myBtn">Subscribe now :)</a></h2>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">Register with Tent a garden</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        {% if registered %}
        
   <h4>Tent a garden says: <strong>thank you for registering!</strong></h4>
   <a href="/">Return to the homepage.</a><br />
   {% else %}
   <h4>Tent a garden says: <strong>register here!</strong></h4><br />
   
   <form id="user_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    {{ profile_form.as_p }}
    
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="Register" />
   </form>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myBtn").click(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal();
   });
  });
 </script>
  
 <h2>Are you already a member? Then, <a href="/login/">login</a>!</h2>
 {% endif %}
```

- views.py

  ```
  from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render, redirect
  from django.template import RequestContext
  from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
  from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
  from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
  from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

  from tentagarden.forms import UserForm, UserProfileForm

  def home(request):
      context = RequestContext(request)

      registered = False

      if request.method == 'POST':
          user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
          profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

          if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
              user = user_form.save()

              user.set_password(user.password)
              user.save()

              profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
              profile.user = user

              if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                  profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']

              profile.save()

              registered = True

          else:
              print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors

      else:
          user_form = UserForm()
          profile_form = UserProfileForm()

      return render_to_response(
              'tentagarden/home.html',
              {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered},
              context)
  ```
- forms.py

  ```
  from django import forms
  from django.forms import ModelForm
  from tentagarden.models import UserProfile
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User

  class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
      password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

      class Meta:
          model = User
          fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

  class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = UserProfile
          fields = ('website', 'picture')
  ```
- models.py

  ```
  from django.db import models
  from django.utils import timezone
  from autoslug import AutoSlugField
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User

  class UserProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User)
      website = models.URLField(blank=True)
      picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.user.username
  ```
- urls.py

  ```
  from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

  urlpatterns = patterns('tentagarden.views',
      url(r'^$', 'home', name='home'),
      url(r'^list/$', 'list', name='list'),
      url(r'^login/$', 'user_login', name='login'),
      url(r'^logout/$', 'user_logout', name='logout'),
  )
  ```

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Which part of this do you want to behave differently? Do you want the modal to pop up automatically if there were errors on the form?

Answer (score 2):

Your form errors are not shown because the form is only displayed when the user has clicked a button.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myBtn").click(function(){
            // You need to be triggering this when there was an error
            $("#myModal").modal();
        });
    });
</script>
```

A simple patch fix would be to pass an extra context variable to the template. Something like `registration_failed = True` or `False`.

Then modify your code like so:

```
# in views.py
else:
    print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors
    return render_to_response(
        'tentagarden/home.html',
        {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered, 'registration_failed': True},
        context)
```

And:

```
<!-- in your HTML -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myBtn").click(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal();
        });
        // If the template is rendered with registration_failed == true
        // Then send a click to the button controlling the modal.
        if ({{registration_failed}}) {
            $("#myBtn").click();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Please note that this is not the best long-term solution to your problem, I think you need to refactor your code a lot. But this will fix the immediate issue.

Comment: What would be the best approach to do this?
I mean, I'm not asking you to do everything for me, but if you could address me to some particular practice, I'd be grateful :)

Comment: I would use a javascript client-side validation method, that way you don't have to have the user post the entire form and reload the page just to say something wasn't typed correctly. Google for `javascript form validation` and see what you can find.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look!

Comment: Is it good practice to control the validation only client-side?

Comment: No, you should definitely do both sides. Bare minimum, server-side only. In your particular case it is a convenience to the user to have validation also occur client-side.